# Was Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker censored in India?

Tags: star-wars, censorship, the-rise-of-skywalker

The Singapore version of *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker* was cut for containing a [same-sex kiss scene](https://www.thehindu.com/entertainment/movies/same-sex-kiss-scene-from-rise-of-skywalker-cut-from-films-singapore-version/article30395062.ece).

Did India have any similar censoring done or did we see the same version as the original?

Comment: If two women are shown kissing at the end of the film, you're seeing original content. It's extremely obvious when it happens, not like it's in the background off to the side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The film passed the Indian Central Board of Film Certification (CBFC) on the 13th December 2019 with [no changes](https://www.cbfcindia.gov.in/cbfcAdmin/search-result.php?recid=MkEwMTIwMTEyMDE5MDAwNDM=).

[image]

*Rise of Skywalker* is available to download in India on streaming channels like Netflix (and was shown in local cinemas) ***in its entirety*** although it did receive a [statutory warning](https://play.google.com/store/movies/details/Star_Wars_The_Rise_of_Skywalker?id=H-YYYrkZvRk&hl=en_GB&gl=US) for containing [strobe lighting and flashing images](https://variety.com/2019/film/news/star-wars-rise-of-skywalker-seizure-risk-flashing-lights-1203427472/).